# Special Characters window no longer resizable in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, window-manager

I upgraded my Mac Pro to OS X Lion (now 10.7.1) a few weeks ago, and am mostly very happy with it. The edge-resizing of Windows is especially nice.

Still, the Special Characters app, which used to have a resizable window from the lower right corner, now has no resizing available at all.

Is there any way to alter this behavior to make this window resizable, or do I just need to wait till Apple recognizes this problem and fixes it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resize the window, but it's different than most windows in Lion.

If you click and drag a corner or an edge, the window will resize. Yes, it doesn't look like you can use the corners, but they do work.
This appears to work with every corner except the top left, which is blocked by the close button. **Edit:** Actually, if you aim just right (to the top left of the close button) you can use that corner too.

**To summarize: Things still work, but the active areas are tiny. You just have to be careful.**

This behavior is strange, and seems buggy to me. I expect than a future update will fix this and allow you to resize by all the corners and edges.

Comment: Verified. And I agree: strange.

Comment: I thought my mouse was broken until I realized this window had wildly different targets for edge resizing than other windows.